На клиенте сервер возвращает неккоректное число
Пишу сайт. На next.js есть такой код:
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/get-table/servers", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({serverId})
            })

            if (response.ok) {
                const servers = await response.json()
            } 

Я проверил с помощью postman, что возвращает мой сервер. Это 1272881954232209419. Но почему-то клиент выводит в логах 1272881954232209400. Подскажите, почему так происходит??

сервер/клиент тут не при чем, это особенность большых чисел, точно не помню что как, но как решение используй строку место чисел, те кто точно знают почему дадут ответ, либо найди инфу и прочитай.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER Считать цифры мне лень, но уверен что ваше число слишком большое. Передавайте его в виде строки, вряд ли вам нужно делать с ним арифметические операции

хорошо щас проверю

$ node, > 1272881954232209419 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, true. Число не может быть записано точно, оно округляется.

Решил, спасибо комментаторам. Я просто на сервере сделал отдельный запрос для этого тупого javascript-а:
@PostMapping("/servers-str")
    public List<String> getServersStringTable() {
        List<ServerModel> servers = serverService.getAllServers();

        return servers.stream()
                .map(server -> String.valueOf(server.getServerId()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

Просто строку возвращаю, вернее, список, а там на клиенте дальше проверяю, как мне нужно.
